# SQLite C/C++ Interface: memory increasing while insert data into table

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I'm a newbie in SQLite. I tried to create data and insert it into a given database through C/C++ interface. The problem is the memory keep increasing when I run the program. The more data are inserted, the more memory is used. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void execute(char* sql, sqlite3 *&db)
{// execute a command
sqlite3_stmt *stm = NULL;
int rc = 0;

rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,sql,-1,&stm,NULL);
rc = sqlite3_step(stm);
sqlite3_finalize(stm);

stm = NULL;

return;
}

int main()
{
char *tam = new char[256];
sqlite3* db;
sqlite3_open("bangso.db",&db);
sprintf(tam,"COMMIT;");
execute(tam,db);
sprintf(tam,"PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;");
execute(tam,db);
sprintf(tam,"PRAGMA count_changes=OFF;");
execute(tam,db);
sprintf(tam,"PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY;");
execute(tam,db);
sprintf(tam,"PRAGMA temp_store=MEMORY;");
execute(tam,db);
sprintf(tam,"BEGIN;");
execute(tam,db);


for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
    sprintf(tam,"insert into bangso(id,so) values(%d,%d);\n",i+1,i);
    execute(tam,db);
    sprintf(tam,"create table a%d(id int);\n",i);
    execute(tam,db);
    if(i%1000==0) printf("> %d\n",int(sqlite3_memory_used()));
}


sprintf(tam,"COMMIT;");
execute(tam,db);
sqlite3_close(db);


delete [] tam;
tam = NULL;

}
```

I feel that the function sqlite3_finalize dose not release all memory. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are creating 10K tables.  Is this intentional?

Comment: @Tim Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite library keeps metadata for all tables in memory. When your database has 10000 tables, you use up memory for those 10000 tables.

Comment: It just increases slower if I skip creating table. But it keep growing.

Comment: The database itself becomes larger. Edit your question to show the additional memory usage per row.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the journal mode to MEMORY, which keeps the rollback journal in memory instead of writing it to disk. You're also doing that with the TEMP_STORE setting, but it doesn't look like you're having to create any temporary tables or indices, so that *shouldn't* be affecting your memory usage. Try `PRAGMA journal_mode=DELETE;`, which is the default journal mode to write the rollback journal to disk.